# Cannot use '.' in Netbeans java files

Tags: java, netbeans

Suddenly, I got a very unusual problem. In NetBeans 7.0 the `.` stopped working in `*.java` files. When opening other documents such as `*.php`, it works correct. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean that "." no longer brings up a list of methods?

Comment: No, the "." doens't come up :-s only after hitting it multiple times. But the keyboard works correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, forgot to tell that I was using windows. For anyone that has the same problem: Reboot your PC!